# What is the difference between DOM parsing, loading, rendering, ready?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to understand how the DOM is rendered, and resources and requested/loaded from the network. However when reading the resources found on internet, DOM parsing/loading/rendering/ready terms are used and I cant seem to grasp what is the order of these 'events'.

When script, css or img file is requested from network, does it stop rendering dom only or stops parsing it also? Is Dom loading same as Dom rendering? and Is DomContentLoaded event equivalent to `jQuery.ready()`?

Can someone please explain if some of these terms are synonymous and in what order they happen?

Comment: http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you open a browser `window`, that window needs to have a `document` loaded into it for the user to see and interact with. But, a user can navigate away from that `document` (while still keeping the same `window` open) and load up another `document`. Of course, the user can close the browser window as well. As such, you can say that the `window` and the `document` have a life-cycle.

The `window` and the `document` are accessible to you via object APIs and you can get involved in the life-cycles of these objects by hooking up functions that should be called during key `events` in the life-cycle of these objects.

The `window` object is at the top of the browser's object model - it is always present (you can't have a `document` if there's no `window` to load it into) and this means that it is the browser's ***Global*** Object. You can talk to it anytime in any JavaScript code.

When you make a request for a document (that would be an HTTP or HTTPS request) and the resource is returned to the client, it comes back in an HTTP or HTTPS response - this is where the data payload (the text, html, css, JavaScript, JSON, XML, etc.) lives.

Let's say that you've requested an .html page. As the browser begins to receive that payload it begins to read the HTML and construct an "in-memory" representation of the `document` object formed from the code. This representation is called The Document Object Model or the DOM.

The act of reading/processing the HTML is called "**parsing**" and when the browser is done doing this, the DOM structure is now complete. This key moment in the life-cycle triggers the document object's [**DOMContentLoaded**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event, which signifies that there is enough information for a fully formed `document` to be interactive. This event is synonymous with jQuery's [**document.ready**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event.

But, before going on, we need to back up a moment... As the browser is parsing  the HTML, it also "**renders**" that content to the screen, meaning that space in the document is allocated for the element and its content and that content is displayed. This doesn't happen AFTER all parsing is complete, the rendering engine works at the same time the parsing engine is working, just one step behind it - - if the parsing engine parses a table-row, for example, the rendering engine will then render it. However, when it comes to things like images, although the image element may have been parsed, the actual image file may not yet have finished downloading to the client.  This is why you may sometimes initially see a page with no images and then as the images begin to appear, the rest of the content on the page has to shift to make room for the image -- the browser knew there was going to be an image, but it didn't necessarily know how much space it was going to need for that image until it arrived.

CSS files, JS files, images and other resources required by the document download in the background, but most browsers/operating systems cap how many HTTP requests can be working simultaneously. I know for Windows, the Windows registry has a setting for IE that caps that at 10 requests at at time, so if a page has 11 images in it, the first 10 will download at the same time, but the 11th will have to wait. This is one of the reasons it is suggested that it's better to combine multiple CSS files into one file and to use image sprites, rather than separate images - - to reduce the overall amount of HTTP requests a page has to make.

When all of the external resources required by the `document` have completed downloading (CSS files, JavaScript files, image files, etc.), the `window` will receive its ["**load**" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event), which signifies that, not only has the DOM structure been built, but all resources are available for use.  This is the event to tap into when your code needs to interact with the content of an external resource - - it must wait for the content to arrive before consuming it.

Now that the `document` is fully loaded in the `window`, anything can happen. The user may click things, press keys to provide input, scroll, etc. All these actions cause events to trigger and any or all of them can be tapped into to launch custom code at just the right time.

When the browser `window` is asked to load a different `document`, there are events that are triggered that signify the end of the document's life, such as the window's [**`beforeunload`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event and ultimately its [**`unload`** event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event).

This is all still a simplification of the total process, but I think it should give you a good overview of how documents are loaded, parsed and rendered within their life-cycle.

Comment: The part about simultaneous loading should be updated now that most browsers and servers use http2, recommendation about aggregating and performance optimisations are different.