# using Django "include" template tag as nested - side effects?

Tags: django, nested, tags, include, jinja2

Does anyone know or have any experience about bad side effects of using "nested include tags"?
(I mean including a template file which itself includes another template)

For example:

file x.html:

`{% include "z.html" %}`

file y.html:

`{% inclide "x.html" %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad side effects are messed up CSS rules and some headache while debugging. It is generally better to keep them rather flat.

`x.html`:

```html
{% extends "_base.html" %}

{% block main_content %}
    <h1>I am X</h1>

    {% include "includes/z.html" %}
    
{% endblock main_content %}
```

`y.html`:

```html
{% block main_content %}
    <h1>I am Y</h1>

    {% include "x.html" %}
    
{% endblock main_content %}
```

`z.html`:

```
<h2>I am Z</h2>
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Check the code:
https://github.com/almazkun/templating

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing `include` and `extends`

Logically, extending a template when used in the likes of a `base.html` is great, and if you design your templates in a way which allows you to extend certain base html files for certain sections of your site. This is generally when they have shared snippets of html, like the main css block, meta block, script block etc..

You can extend `n` number of times.

Where you are getting confused with include, is that this is more for including snippets of code which are additive or sort of "drop-in" and great examples would be sidebars, navbars, and even custom css or javascript!

The question is, do you want to shared html snippets, or do you want to add extra snippets to certain sections but not others?

If its the latter, you'll want include, and for the former, you'll want extends.

Edit #1:
You have asked for clarity regarding the drawbacks of the two aforementioned template tags. As I sit here and ponder that question, I cant think of any significant disadvantages of using either `include` or `extends` providing that you have used them where they should be used. If you have used an include, where actually you should have used extended the template, you may find, as is described in someone else's answer, that css rules may not be applied in the way you would expect them to be.

Comment: Really useful points. Thanks for them. But anyway I also want to know the bad consequences too

Comment: Added an edit, sorry I can't be more helpful with this point.

Comment: thank you my friend, for your best

Answer (score 1):

The question is about nested `include` tags and the answers show that "there is no actual problem if you know what you expect and how to handle it".

There is a paragraph in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) about the `include` tag that sets some limits, nonetheless:

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render
> this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate
> and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means
> that there is no shared state between included templates – each
> include is a completely independent rendering process.

- Trying to make ends meet about rendering and parsing:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35966477/2996101
- [Shared state between included templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38901106/2996101) is a complicated issue even for big front end frameworks, such as React.

Answer (score 0):

No problem! It's usual to use inheritance in Django templates. You can make a template with some blocks and override blocks in children templates and children of children can override or use superblock content.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, dear friend. I know these substitute ways. My question is another thing.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: explained above in the post, the best way possible. pls read again...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any issues chaining include. You might have issues if have extend or blocks with similar names in the included template.

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues when you include a number of templates.

for example
base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    {% block title %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

a.html

```
<h1>I am from A</h1>
```

b.html

```
<h2>I am from B</h2>
```

c.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}<title>Welcome in C!</title>{% endblock %}
<h3>I am from C . I am mother of A and B </h3>
{% block content %}
{% include 'a.html' %}
{% include 'b.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```